# ruby and splitting strings with regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string like

```
"A;BB;C[1;22];DDD[11;2;33];EEEEE[1111]"
```

I will split this into

```
["A","BB","C[1;22]","DDD[11;2;33]","EEEEE[1111]"]
```

The chars and the numbers are representatives for any strings of 1-x chars length.

My regex is like

```
/(?<!(\w+)\[)(\;(?!((\w+)((\;)(\w+)){0,}\])))/
```

https://regex101.com/r/fWNHBB/2

But I don't get it run in ruby. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Do not use `;(?![^\[]*\])` as it only checks if there is a `]` to the right of the current locaton after any zero or more non-`[` chars. It does not check if there is a `[` anywhere to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```rb
text.scan(/(?:\[[^\]\[]*\]|[^;])+/)
```

*Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `\]` - a `]` char
- `|` - or

  - `[^;]`  - any single char other than a `;` char
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times.

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/oFDFv6):

```rb
text = "A;BB;C[1;22];DDD[11;2;33];EEEEE[1111]"
puts text.scan(/(?:\[[^\]\[]*\]|[^;])+/)
```

Output:

```
A
BB
C[1;22]
DDD[11;2;33]
EEEEE[1111]
```

Answer (score -1):

I have assumed brackets are matching and not overlapping. That is, every left bracket is followed by a right bracket with no left or right bracket between and every right bracket is preceded by a left bracket with no left or right bracket between.

With that proviso you can do that as follows.

```
str = "A;BB;C[1;22];DDD[11;2;33];EEEEE[1111]"
```

```
rgx = /;(?![^\[\]]*\])/
```

```
str.split(rgx)
  #=> ["A", "BB", "C[1;22]", "DDD[11;2;33]", "EEEEE[1111]"]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/umcKox/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
;           # match ';'
(?!         # begin negative lookahead
  [^\[\]]*  # match >= chars other than '[' and ']'
  \]        # match ']'
)           # end negative lookahead
```

---

One could use the following regular expression to confirm that brackets are matching and not overlapping.

```
\A[^\[\]]*(?:\[[^\[\]]*\][^\[\]]*)*[^\[\]]*\z
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zXEoIz/1)